# How to stop error messages appearing in terminal when running programs?

Tags: command-line, logging

Lots of Ubuntu programs write error messages all over the terminal.   This has been happening for as long as I can remember.

1. If these are bugs like the messages say, why don't they ever get fixed?
2. If the messages are not useful, why are they generated at all?
3. Is there a way to suppress them all?

E.g.:

```
$ evince foo.pdf &

[2] 16612
$ ### BUG ###
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

$ gvim exponential_model_exact_equilibrium_00.cc

(gvim:16664): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

$ acroread foo.pdf

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(acroread:16674): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you assume that log output is "not useful"? Why do you run these applications from terminal if you aren't interested in their output?

Answer (score 5):

1. You're probably welcome to submit a fix
2. The fact that they are not useful to *you* does not mean they have no use.
3. Try `command 2> /dev/null`.